# Can a command be run on a specific port on the same host machine?

Tags: linux, ssh, gerrit

I want to execute the following command.

```
ssh -p 29418 localhost gerrit gsql
```

I am running the `gerrit` service on an `ubuntu` VM. Here, an `ssh` connection is made for making a connection with the same host's `localhost` from the same ubuntu VM. Is an `ssh` connection required to execute this ? Is there a way to run this command on the same machine, on this particular `port`, on `localhost`, without an `ssh` connection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have to run commands using the Gerrit Internal SSH Daemon only.

From the [documentation](https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/cmd-index.html#_server):

> Aside from the standard Git server side actions, Gerrit supports several other commands over its internal SSH daemon. As Gerrit does not provide an interactive shell, the commands must be triggered from an ssh client, for example...